# Mapping structure before copying values

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping, struct

Below is the solidity code which add instructors :-

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Courses {
    
    struct Instructor {
        uint age;
        string fName;
        string lName;
    }
    
    mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;     /// LINE 1
    address[] public instructorAccts;
    
    function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string _fName, string _lName) public {
        Instructor storage instructor = instructors[_address];   /// LINE 2
        
        instructor.age = _age;          /// LINE 3
        instructor.fName = _fName;          /// LINE 4
        instructor.lName = _lName;         /// LINE 5
        
        instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
    }
    
    function getInstructors() view public returns(address[]) {
        return instructorAccts;
    }
    
    function getInstructor(address _address) view public returns (uint, string, string) {
        return (instructors[_address].age, instructors[_address].fName, instructors[_address].lName);
    }
    
    function countInstructors() view public returns (uint) {
        return instructorAccts.length;
    }
    
}
```

I know that in mapping , key value is used to fetch data value. So can anyone explain how `LINE 2` helps copying value into `_address`. Like it is `var instructor = instructors[_address];` , so it means the structure stored at value  `_address`  will be copied in  struct `instructor` of LHS. In line 3,4,5 we are copying values in struct `instructor` so how those values will be copied  at address `_address` in `instructors[_address]` ?

Answer (score 0):

`Instructor storage instructor` is just a pointer to `instructors[_address]`. So lines 3,4,5 are writing directly to the state mapping with key `_address`.

This is because the code uses the `storage` keyword, and not `memory`: the first creates a pointer, the second copies to a new variable.

This code is 100% equivalent:

```
function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string _fName, string _lName) public {
        
        instructors[_address].age = _age;          /// LINE 3
        instructors[_address].fName = _fName;          /// LINE 4
        instructors[_address].lName = _lName;         /// LINE 5
        
        instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
    }
```

Comment: On the official site - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour .

The 4th point states that "All other assignments to storage always copy.". So I think it should copy and not create a pointer. I apologize if I am wrong somewhere since I am a newbie. If I a wrong then please correct me.

Comment: Yeah, but we are in the 3rd pointer: "assignments from storage to a *local* storage variable also only assign a reference".

Comment: I think function parametres are always memory variables. Isn't `instructors[_address]` a memory variable ?

Comment: No, it's a state variable. It's reading a mapping value saved on storage. If you want to save the value on memory you can write `Instructor memory instructor = instructors[_address]`, this way creating a copy and not reference. External function parameter can't be storage you're right, but in this case the only parameter is `_address`, so I'm not sure why it's relevant.

Comment: So let me get this straight , as per you `instructors[_address]` is a storage state variable because data supposedly yet to stored at `_address` is permanent stored .And since `Instructor storage instructor` is also a storage so this is a storage to storage case. Hence , "Assignments from storage to a local storage variable also only assign a reference."
Am I right ??

Comment: Yes you got it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know I might be have been bit difficult to grasp but you were very helpful.....Thank youvery very much.